# Question on how to use mask on 1d and 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working with a logistic regression model, and I want to mask values for x and y before making the training of the test, and mask them again after for the prediction. However, I encounter issues that have to do (presumably) with the shape of x, y and the other 2 variables I use for the mask.

This is the part where I mask the initial x and y, and then mask again X_test and y_test for predictions:

```
# Initial mask for training 
regmask = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y) & (survey > 2010) & (h == 40)
print("Initial variables shape ", x.shape, y.shape, survey.shape, h.shape)

print()

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x[regmask].reshape(-1,1), y[regmask], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Create the logistic regression model
model = LogisticRegression()

# Fit the model to the training data
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Test variables shape ", X_test.shape, y_test.shape, survey.shape, h.shape)
print(np.sum(np.isfinite(x)), np.sum(np.isfinite(y)), np.sum(survey > 2010), np.sum((h >= 28) & (h <= 36)), np.sum((h >= 20) & (h <= 28)))


# New mask for predictions
mask = np.isfinite(X_test) & np.isfinite(y_test)
h_masked = h[mask]
survey_masked = survey[mask]
predmask = mask.flatten() & np.isfinite(survey_masked) & (((h_masked >= 28) & (h_masked <= 36)) | ((h_masked >= 20) & (h_masked <= 28)))
```

The output for the 2 print statements and all of the code you see should clarify better what is the error I am getting:

```
Initial variables shape  (293240,) (293240,) (293240,) (293240,)

Test variables shape  (1754, 1) (1754,) (293240,) (293240,)
147196 147196 146930 14570 10730
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 61
     59 # Predictions on new mask for hours
     60 mask = np.isfinite(X_test) & np.isfinite(y_test)
---> 61 h_masked = h[mask]
     62 survey_masked = survey[mask]
     63 predmask = mask.flatten() & np.isfinite(survey_masked) & (((h_masked >= 28) & (h_masked <= 36)) | ((h_masked >= 20) & (h_masked <= 28)))

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Can anybody help me figure out how can I solve this? Am I doing it right by masking the h and survey variables again or is it pointless?

EDIT: found a solution as follows:

```
# Initial regmask for fitting logit on training data 
regmask = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y) & (survey > 2010) & (h == 40)
print("Initial variables shape ", x.shape, y.shape, survey.shape, h.shape)

X_train, y_train = x[regmask].reshape(-1,1), y[regmask]

# Create the logistic regression model
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Creating predmask for new x_pred and y_pred
predmask = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y) & (survey > 2010) & ((h >= 20) & (h <= 28) | (h >= 28) & (h <= 36))
X_test, y_test = x[predmask].reshape(-1, 1), y[predmask]

# Checking input variables shape
print("Predicting variables shape ", x[predmask].shape, y[predmask].shape, survey.shape, h.shape)
print("Number of samples in X_pred:", X_test.shape[0])

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

`X_train` and `X_test` variables contain 2d arrays, because you reshaped your initial data from 1d to 2d in this line: `x[regmask].reshape(-1,1)`. To avoid IndexError you need to return `X_test` back to 1d like this:

```
mask = np.isfinite(X_test.reshape(-1)) & np.isfinite(y_test)
```

P.S. Original question has one more mistake, since we need to save the correspondence between `x`, `survey` and `h` after data splitting. That why it is better to combine the input data in one dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'survey': survey, 'h': h})

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[regmask], y[regmask], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train.x.reshape(-1, 1), y_train) # survey and h are not used in original training, that why we use only x column

# New mask for predictions
mask = np.isfinite(X_test.x) & np.isfinite(y_test.x)
predmask = mask.flatten() & np.isfinite(X_test.survey) & (((X_test.h >= 28) & (X_test.h <= 36)) | ((X_test.h >= 20) & (X_test.h <= 28)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is true. However, I have another IndexError now because the shape of 'h' and 'survey' are still different:

Test variables shape  (1754,) (1754,) (293240,) (293240,)

And it gives me the error:

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 293240 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1754

Comment: I completed my previous answer by some additional manipulations, may be they will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the line model.fit(X_train.x.reshape(-1, 1), y_train) doesnt work because the x is a series from the dataframe, which doesn't have a reshape() method. I get the point you are making for keeping the correspondence between the variables, though